# Is there an keras function for compare two variable without getting value of "symbolic" tensors?

Tags: python, keras, loss-function

I'm writing a custom loss function in keras. I want to compare two tensors, but Metrics, losses, and the entire model are "symbolic" tensors. This means they have absolutely no data (or value) until the moment we start fitting or predicting.

So I want to know is there a way to avoid getting value

I have tried `K.eval()` and `K.greater()` as following:

```
def SeedFillNew(_binImg):
    area_list = K.variable(value=1, dtype='float32', name='std')
    area = K.variable(value=1, dtype='float32', name='area')
    label = 0                                  #  start by 1 
    rows,cols = 512,512
    mask = np.zeros((rows, cols),dtype = np.uint8)
    for i in range(0 , rows):
        for j in range(0 , cols):
            if  _binImg[i,j] >0.5  and mask[i,j] !=1  :
```

```
def SeedFillNew(_binImg):
    area_list = K.variable(value=1, dtype='float32', name='std')
    area = K.variable(value=1, dtype='float32', name='area')
    thresh = K.variable(value=0.5, dtype='float32', name='thresh')
    label = 0                                  #  start by 1 
    rows,cols = 512,512
    mask = np.zeros((rows, cols),dtype = np.uint8)
    for i in range(0 , rows):
        for j in range(0 , cols):
            if  K.greater(_binImg[i,j],thresh)  and mask[i,j] !=1  :
```

I get:

> Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as `tf.cond` to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.